# MongoDB: How to get an average of duration between timestamp?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's my documents:

```
[
  {_id: 1, timestamp: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
  {_id: 2, timestamp: ISODate("2017-01-01T02:00:00.000Z")},
  {_id: 3, timestamp: ISODate("2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z")},
  {_id: 4, timestamp: ISODate("2017-01-01T08:00:00.000Z")}
]
```

I want to make a query to Mongodb to get an average duration between these documents. In this example, it should print: `2.667`, which is derived from

`(08:00 - 05:00) + (05:00 - 02:00) + (02:00 - 00:00) / 3`

I know that I can write a simple coding to process this, but I want to know whether it is possible in `mongodb`? Thank you

PS: it would be better if it can be written using aggregation framework

Comment: Aggregation works with individual documents, while you need to compare 2 consecutive documents. It might be possible to use $bucketAuto to group documents, but it really doesn't worth it.